# SVG rect as background to text

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following in an SVG:

```html
<g transform="translate(1420 1030)">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="36" class="user-1"></rect>
<image id="my-user-avatar" x="3" y="3" width="30" height="30" xlink:href="/img/user/default-avatar.png"/>
<text id="my-user-nickname" x="40" y="23">USER</text>
</g>
```

If the text is greater than a certain number of letters it overflows the `rect`.

How do I generate in SVG the effect of a div with a background color where it grows in width based on its content, and keeps a padding to the right of 3px?

Comment: Can we have an absolute URL to the image please?

Comment: Hi @Aydin, I do not understand the Q.

Comment: @TheReapPapa /img/user/default-avatar.png - URL to this image

Comment: I still do not understand. The image is on my dev server. Why is the absolute url important?